# If a timestamp in one table is between two time stamps in another table, then increment by 1 using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, increment

**Summary of the Problem:**

I would like to calculate the number of ambulances on a response at any given minute of the day over an entire calendar year.
Two pandas dataframes are generated; The first is the emergency responses of ambulances showing the starting time stamp of the emergency and the ending time stamp for that ambulance emergency.This data comes from our database. For example, an ambulance responded to a cardiac arrest at 2020-01-01 00:30:17 and the ambulance was cleared from this response at 2020-01-01 00:38:05.000. Let's call this dataframe "emergency_event".

The second pandas dataframe takes the minimum value of the emergency_event and the maximum value. It generates a dataframe using the min and max time stamps as the starting and ending points of another dataframe. It increments by one minute from starting point to ending point and generates a zero as a place holder for the number of trucks working. Let's call this second dataframe "coincident" because we want to count the number of ambulances working coincidentally within that one minute time frame.

In other words, the first emergency event started at "2020-01-01 00:00:28" so the "coincident" events table would take this value and increment by one minute until the very last emergency_event ending time stamp. For example the "coincident" table would look like:

```
calendar_timestamp      TrucksWorking

2020-01-01 00:00:28              0

2020-01-01 00:01:28              0

2020-01-01 00:02:28              0

2020-01-01 00:03:28              0

2020-01-01 00:04:28              0

2020-01-01 00:05:28              0

......
```

Notice how it increments by one minute and there is a placeholder of zero for the number of ambulances working.

There are now two dataframes: An "emergency_event" and a "coincident" table.
The goal of the program is to use the first observation of the "coincident" table and evaluate against every row of the "emergency_events" table. **Does the time stamp of the "coincident" observation occur between the StartTime and EndTime of the "emergency_events"?** If True, then increment the TrucksWorking value by 1. Loop through every "coincident" observation and evaluate if it is in between any of the "emergency_events" and increment by 1 if True.

At the end of the program this will generate a dataframe of one minute increments and the number of ambulances working at that time. Using this data I can statistically analyze the number of ambulances working at any given time and even parse it out by hour of day, weekday, daytime/nighttime, etc. This is very powerful information.

But I am stuck on the logic and I need your help. Specifically, I can't figure out how to make "coincident" table add 1 when its timestamp is within the "emergency_events" table.

**What I have tried**

```
for each in coincident.calendar_timestamp:
    if (coincident[coincident['calendar_timestamp']] >= emergency_events[emergency_events['StartTime']] & coincident[coincident['calendar_timestamp']] <= emergency_events[emergency_events['EndTime']]):
        coincident[coincident['TrucksWorking']] = coincident[coincident['TrucksWorking']] + 1
    else:
        coincident[coincident['TrucksWorking']]
```

**I have also attempted:**

```
# =============================================================================
# I have attempted the following
# the following code returns an error message
# ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
# =============================================================================
## for each in coincident.calendar_timestamp:
##     if (coincident[coincident['calendar_timestamp'].between(starting_point, ending_point)]):
##         coincident[coincident['TrucksWorking']] = coincident[coincident['TrucksWorking']] + 1
##     else:
##         coincident[coincident['TrucksWorking']]

# =============================================================================
# I have attempted the following
# a dead end code that I cannot make work
# df = coincident[coincident['calendar_timestamp'].between(starting_point, ending_point)]
# print(df.head(n = 5))
# =============================================================================

# =============================================================================
# I have attempted the following but it will not work
# another dead end code
# for timestamp in coincident_events.calendar:
#     print(coincident_events.calendar.query('coincident_events.calendar >= emergency_events.starting_point and coincident_events.calendar <= emergency_events.ending_point'))
# =============================================================================
```

**Show my code:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Python 3.7 Anaconda distribution
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# =============================================================================
# Step 1: Read in the ambulance runs with a starting and ending time values
# call this dataframe "emergency_events"
# =============================================================================

# the following array is a small sample when an ambulance starts a call and when it ends a call
data = [['2020-01-01 00:00:28.000','2020-01-01 00:35:28.987']
        , ['2020-01-01 00:02:34.000','2020-01-01 01:05:13.540']
        , ['2020-01-01 00:03:57.000','2020-01-01 01:14:44.537']
        , ['2020-01-01 00:06:17.000','2020-01-01 01:26:52.087']
        , ['2020-01-01 00:13:20.000','2020-01-01 01:17:31.310']
        , ['2020-01-01 00:14:01.000','2020-01-01 01:57:28.343']
        , ['2020-01-01 00:16:11.000','2020-01-01 00:39:34.967']
        , ['2020-01-01 00:22:03.000','2020-01-01 01:46:40.037']
        , ['2020-01-01 00:23:07.000','2020-01-01 00:49:25.890']
        , ['2020-01-01 00:23:19.000','2020-01-01 01:26:39.920']
        , ['2020-01-01 00:30:17.000','2020-01-01 00:38:05.000']] 

#convert the array to a pandas data frame
emergency_events = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['StartTime', 'EndTime'])

#convert the string values to date time values
emergency_events['StartTime'] = pd.to_datetime(emergency_events['StartTime'])
emergency_events['EndTime'] = pd.to_datetime(emergency_events['EndTime'])

# =============================================================================
# Step 2 Create a calendar of date time stamps incremented by 1 minute using the ambulance runs min/max values
# call this dataframe "coincident"
# =============================================================================

## establish a starting value based on the first ambulance event
starting_point = emergency_events.StartTime.min()
print(starting_point)
## establish an ending value based on the final ambulance call ending time.
ending_point = emergency_events.EndTime.max()
print(ending_point)
## create a range of time stamps incremented by 1 minute from starting point to ending point
days = pd.date_range(starting_point, ending_point, freq='min')

## create a pandas dataframe with two columns: calendar for time stamps and a place holder of 0 for trucks working 
coincident = pd.DataFrame({'calendar_timestamp': days, 'TrucksWorking': 0})
## print it out to verify the data
print(coincident.head(n = 5))

# =============================================================================
# Step 3 --- now for the difficult part
# if a "coincident" time stamp is between a start and end time of an emergency_event
# increment the TrucksWorking column by 1
# loop through every "coincident" observation and test if it is between a start and an end of an "emergency_event"
# =============================================================================
for each in coincident.calendar_timestamp:
    if (coincident[coincident['calendar_timestamp']] >= emergency_events[emergency_events['StartTime']] & coincident[coincident['calendar_timestamp']] <= emergency_events[emergency_events['EndTime']]):
        coincident[coincident['TrucksWorking']] = coincident[coincident['TrucksWorking']] + 1
    else:
        coincident[coincident['TrucksWorking']]

## at the end of this program it should return a calendar of date time stamps with 
## the number of ambulances at work during that one minute interval.
## this information can be used for data modeling.

# =============================================================================
# I have attempted the following
# the following code returns an error message
# ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
# =============================================================================
## for each in coincident.calendar_timestamp:
##     if (coincident[coincident['calendar_timestamp'].between(starting_point, ending_point)]):
##         coincident[coincident['TrucksWorking']] = coincident[coincident['TrucksWorking']] + 1
##     else:
##         coincident[coincident['TrucksWorking']]

# =============================================================================
# I have attempted the following
# a dead end code that I cannot make work
# df = coincident[coincident['calendar_timestamp'].between(starting_point, ending_point)]
# print(df.head(n = 5))
# =============================================================================

# =============================================================================
# I have attempted the following but it will not work
# another dead end code
# for timestamp in coincident_events.calendar:
#     print(coincident_events.calendar.query('coincident_events.calendar >= emergency_events.starting_point and coincident_events.calendar <= emergency_events.ending_point'))
# =============================================================================

print(coincident.head(n = 20))

# =============================================================================
# Step 4: verify the "coincident" table is correct and then analyze the data
# Printing the "coincident" dataframe should look something like:
# =============================================================================
#     StartTime                       TrucksWorking    
# 0  2020-01-01 00:00:28              1
# 1  2020-01-01 00:01:28              1
# 2  2020-01-01 00:02:28              1
# 3  2020-01-01 00:03:28              1
# 4  2020-01-01 00:04:28              2
# 5  2020-01-01 00:05:28              2
# 6  2020-01-01 00:06:28              3
# 7  2020-01-01 00:07:28              3
# 8  2020-01-01 00:08:28              3
# 9  2020-01-01 00:09:28              3
# 10 2020-01-01 00:10:28              3
# etc for a full calendar year of ambulance responses

# =============================================================================
# Step 5: analyze the data looking for patterns of ambulance utilization. TBD
# =============================================================================
```

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: You would like to calculate the #number of ambulances on a response at any given minute of the day over an entire calendar year?

Comment: Yes, mozart_kv467, I would like to count the number of ambulances that are running a response and I would like this calculation to be made for every minute of the calendar year. For example, on 1 June 2020 at 12:00:00 there are eleven ambulances running calls. Then at 12:01:00 another ambulance is dispatched so now there are twelve ambulances running calls. This data will allow me to analyze patterns in the emergency services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your data I found the following solution. I used only the **first 200 minutes of the year 2020** but you can change that easily by adjusting `periods=200` to the number of minutes per year.

I used the following `variables` : 
`df` corresponds to your coincident-dataframe. I generated it upfront for every minute from Januar 1, 2020:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['time1'] = pd.date_range('2020-01-01 00:00:00', periods=200, freq='min')
df['trucks working'] = 0
print(df)
```

This gives me the minutes of the year still with all **trucks working = 0**:

```
                  time1  trucks working
0   2020-01-01 00:00:00               0
1   2020-01-01 00:01:00               0
2   2020-01-01 00:02:00               0
3   2020-01-01 00:03:00               0
4   2020-01-01 00:04:00               0
..                  ...             ...
195 2020-01-01 03:15:00               0
196 2020-01-01 03:16:00               0
197 2020-01-01 03:17:00               0
198 2020-01-01 03:18:00               0
199 2020-01-01 03:19:00               0
```

Using your emergency calls as `data`

```
data = [['2020-01-01 00:00:28.000','2020-01-01 00:35:28.987']
    , ['2020-01-01 00:02:34.000','2020-01-01 01:05:13.540']
    , ['2020-01-01 00:03:57.000','2020-01-01 01:14:44.537']
    , ['2020-01-01 00:06:17.000','2020-01-01 01:26:52.087']
    , ['2020-01-01 00:13:20.000','2020-01-01 01:17:31.310']
    , ['2020-01-01 00:14:01.000','2020-01-01 01:57:28.343']
    , ['2020-01-01 00:16:11.000','2020-01-01 00:39:34.967']
    , ['2020-01-01 00:22:03.000','2020-01-01 01:46:40.037']
    , ['2020-01-01 00:23:07.000','2020-01-01 00:49:25.890']
    , ['2020-01-01 00:23:19.000','2020-01-01 01:26:39.920']
    , ['2020-01-01 00:30:17.000','2020-01-01 00:38:05.000']]
```

I add colum names and name the resulting dataframe `emergency_events`  :

```
 emergency_events = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['StartTime', 'EndTime'])
```

Now I can iterate over the dataframe `emergency_events`

and increment the `'trucks working'`
for each minute of the day that is
between a row of `'StartTime'` and `'EndTime'`

```
for index2, row2 in df.iterrows():
for index, row in emergency_events.iterrows():
    if pd.to_datetime(row['StartTime']) <= pd.to_datetime(row2['time1']) <= pd.to_datetime(row['EndTime']):
        #print(row2['trucks working'])
        #print(row['StartTime'],row2['time1'],row['EndTime'])
        df.at[index2,'trucks working'] += 1
```

This gives me a dataframe with the number of trucks for each minute in the day.

```
time1  trucks working
0   2020-01-01 00:00:00               0
1   2020-01-01 00:01:00               1
2   2020-01-01 00:02:00               1
3   2020-01-01 00:03:00               2
4   2020-01-01 00:04:00               3
..                  ...             ...
195 2020-01-01 03:15:00               0
196 2020-01-01 03:16:00               0
197 2020-01-01 03:17:00               0
198 2020-01-01 03:18:00               0
199 2020-01-01 03:19:00               0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your thoughtful reply. It works well.